# Visual studio 2005 freezes/hangs when switching to design view

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I create a new blank form and the tried to switch to design mode and the ide locks up and uses 100% of one of my CPUs. I have to forcibly kill it to get back into a workable ide. Everything seems fine when viewing the source code. I tried this both in existing project (that works on someone else's machine), and a brand new solution, both with the same outcome. I'm working on a WinXP pro box with all updates installed.

Performing the actions recommended below (attaching a debugger and pausing execution) shows that it is stuck here:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]
```

> System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pen pen, int x, int y, int width, int height) + 0x3d bytes
>       System.Drawing.dll!System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.Pen pen, System.Drawing.Rectangle rect) + 0x14 bytes
>       System.Design.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Design.PanelDesigner.DrawBorder(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics) + 0x97 bytes
>       System.Design.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Design.PanelDesigner.OnPaintAdornments(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs pe = {ClipRectangle = {System.Drawing.Rectangle}}) + 0x50 bytes
>       System.Design.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xd1e bytes 
>       System.Design.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Design.ScrollableControlDesigner.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m = {System.Windows.Forms.Message}) + 0x12 bytes
>       System.Design.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Design.ControlDesigner.DesignerWindowTarget.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x55 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes
>       System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg = 15, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x57 bytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of the hang is a custom control which enters an infinite loop during it's initialization is being displayed in the design form.  The easiest way to check this is to let Visual Studio freeze, then use another instance of Visual Studio to attach to the process.  Break the execution and it should reveal the cause of the hang on the call stack.

Comment: I gave that a shot, I just have 3 threads running Main, <No Name>, and <No Name>. The Main thread's call stack just says [External Code]. So that wasn't very useful. I'm thinking I might just have to reinstall.

Comment: @darrickc right click on the External Code and choose the "Show External Code" option.

Comment: Brilliant, I added the results to the question above.

Comment: @darrickc it looks like it's dying some where in native code.  You can try and attach with both native and manage debugging and it should give you a bit more data about where.  You'll need to add the Microsoft public symbol server http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Answer (score 1):

Design view is resource intensive.

My suggestions

- switch to it and take a coffee break
- don't use it at all (use View in browser to see the HTML)
- Try upgrading your machine

Comment: Wow, I did the "switch and go to a meeting" method, and it worked! Now I have to see how long it actually takes to initialize.

Comment: Its a royal PITA and doesn't even help after a while.

Comment: I just tried it again, and timed it. I quit after waiting 35 minutes.

Comment: I'll also add that this isn't a web based solution, so there is no HTML.